# ExtJS 4 JSON not updating/writing

Tags: javascript, json, apache, extjs, extjs-mvc

I am learning ExtJS 4 and I'm trying to write updated results from a grid to a json file, I can read the values but when I try to update them nothing gets updated. I'm running Apache on Mint, I've also set the htdocs folder and everything inside to chmod 777 in case permissions were messing with my json writing. No luck there :(

Here is my code:
Model:

```
Ext.define('APP.model.RiverModel', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',

    autoSync : true,

fields : [
{
    name : 'id',
    type : 'int',
},
{
    name : 'river',
    type : 'string',
},
{
    name : 'len',
    type : 'int',
}
],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: 'app/data/Lengths.json',
        create: 'app/data/updateLengths.json',
        destroy: 'app/data/updateLengths.json',
        update: 'app/data/updateLengths.json'
    },
    actionMethods: {
            create : 'POST',
            read   : 'POST',
            update : 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'rivers',
        successProperty: 'success'
    },
    writer:
    {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'rivers',
        writeAllFields : false,  
        allowSingle :false
    },
},
```

});

Store:

```
Ext.define('APP.store.LevelDb', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
autoLoad : true,
autoSync : true,
model : 'APP.model.RiverModel',
```

});
console.log('store load');

Controller update function:

```
lineSave: function(button) {
    var win = button.up('window'),
        form = win.down('form'),
        record = form.getRecord(),
        values = form.getValues();
        values.len = parseInt(values.len);
        //values.len = 555;
        console.log(values);
        record.set(values);
        win.close();
        this.getLevelDbStore().sync();
},
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to update the actual **.json** file via ExtJS (e.g., JavaScript), you're not going to have any luck. If you need to update the file, you'll need to do that using some server-side technology that has access to the file you want to update.

Comment: Thanks :) I passed the JSON trough PHP and used file_put_contents() :P